# Is there any sense on testing apps on old iPhones / iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, ios, testing

Does make any sense today, with the incoming iPhone 5, to test apps on old 3GS iPhones or older devices?

Is the simulator enough for a basic app not using OpenGL that runs smootly on iPhone 4???

Can you share marketshare or stats about old iphone / ipod models?

Comment: There are some votes to "close" the question. Maybe programming.stackexchange would be more suited for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to support the older device, be sure to set your deployment target to ideally match the version just after the maximum iOS version allowed for the non-supported device.  In this way, it shouldn't be installable on a device you are not supporting.  Just my 0.02 cents.

Answer (score 1):

It's not essential, plus with all the new API's and features coming out on new devices it's unlikely that many apps will even support older devices however that's not to say they shouldn't as there is still a large number of people using older devices. However for the most part so long as all the things you use in your app like frameworks etc are available on the older OS's and devices then your app should run fine and without the need to test them on the older devices themselves.

On Xcode you can check which features and frameworks work on which OS / devices to help with compatibility with different devices. Also setting the deployment target to ensure that only people with the correct OS / Device can get your app can stop compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

The **third question** is irrelevant. You have to find the data you need by yourself. Every company will look for a different data. This is a programming forum, why bother with market data?

Regarding the **second question**, simulator is usually enough but with older models you never know (push notifications? some library not supported but it is supported in the simulator?). I strongly recommend to test on real devices.

And finally, the **first question**:
For you, what is the purpose of tests? Do you want to support old devices or not? In an ideal world, if you answer yes, you should definitely test on them. If no... then you don't test.

BUT we don't live in an ideal work. To test or not to test is often a bussiness decision. QA is not here to deliver perfect applications. QA is here to make applications good enough. You can't ever test everything. Even if you test everything, users will find a lot of bugs.

So, my final recommendations: If you have the resources to test, then test. If you don't have them, do basic tests on the simulator and then let users do the tests. If they find a bug, you can fix it.